# How to replicate some traffic on Kubernetes and divert it to the Service for investigation

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm using istio and I know that I can define weights in Virtual Service and divert traffic to different services.

My question is: how to amplify some of the traffic and direct the amplified traffic to the validation service? This amplified traffic will not go back to the original source but will be closed within the cluster. In other words, it does not bother the user.

[image: sample]

I'm not even sure if there is an ecosystem, feature or application that provides this kind of mechanism. I don't even know if there is an ecosystem or application that provides such a mechanism and I don't know what it is called, so I'm having trouble finding it.

Thanks.

Comment: this....? https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/mirroring/

Comment: This is what most people would recommend using. If you feel comfortable, post an answer for your own question (just maybe something more than just a link). If not, I will post a CW for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP found a soultion by themselves, in the comments, hence the CW.

---

In this scenario, the best solution is to use Istio [Mirroring](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/mirroring/) - also called shadowing.

> When traffic gets mirrored, the requests are sent to the mirrored service with their Host/Authority headers appended with `-shadow`. For example, `cluster-1` becomes `cluster-1-shadow`.
>
> Also, it is important to note that these requests are mirrored as “fire and forget”, which means that the responses are discarded.

To create mirroring rule, you have to create VirtualService with `mirror` and `mirrorPercentage` fields.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  hosts:
    - httpbin
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: httpbin
        subset: v1
      weight: 100
    mirror:
      host: httpbin
      subset: v2
    mirrorPercentage:
      value: 100.0
```

> This route rule sends 100% of the traffic to v1. The last stanza specifies that you want to mirror (i.e., also send) 100% of the same traffic to the httpbin:v2 service.

<sup>[[source](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/mirroring/#mirroring-traffic-to-v2)]</sup>